# does it make sense to have a wordpress database for a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, wordpress

i was wondering does it make sense to have a wordpress-compatible db for a rails app? i currently have a rails app and its quite functional. one of my bosses suggested to delete my rails database on heroku and instead use a wordpress-compatible database. his reasoning was so that it would be easy to add a bunch of different plug-ins into the system (since wordpress has so many)

i feel kinda opposed to this, wouldn't this require rewriting all my models? not to mention, heroku uses postgres while wordpress uses mysql? and also many other compatibility issues?

does this make sense? or should i just stick with the 'original' database rails uses?

my site is mostly dynamic pages. we hope to eventually have a large user database, and also time is somewhat of an issue.

thanks = )

Comment: If the reason is plugins I don't think going the hard way (rewriting everything) is a good way. If Wordpress plugins are the issue, why not just stick with Wordpress?

Comment: unfortunately the app is already written in rails, but one of the bosses started a liking towards the easy plug-in features wordpress has. i eventually have to talk with him if its feasible or if we should just stuck with rails completely (which i would rather do) but i was trying to see if this makes sense to other people as well

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, you'll be effectively starting over from scratch if you ditch your Rails/Ruby/Postgres for Wordpress/PHP/MySQL. I can't make that decision for you, obvs, but it does not seem to make sense from my perspective.